# Python running bash script and generate OSError

Tags: python, bash, simplehttpserver

I have a bash script which helps establish a local `SimpleHTTPServer`.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I have put this inside my project folder. While I am running the program by using:

```
subprocess.call('./setup.sh')
```

an error message comes out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.call('./setup.sh')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I retried this in terminal

```
localhost:Desktop XXXX$ sh setup.sh
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...
```

It is working fine.
I remember there are a few times where the terminal has popped up a window ask me about the permission for python about something related to firewall and I allowed it. Can you help me?

Comment: You probably need to set the executable bit on `setup.sh`.

Comment: Run it as root (sudo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it exactly as you would on the shell, i.e., as `sh ./setup.sh`:

```
subprocess.call('sh ./setup.sh', shell=True)
```

That should do the trick.  Most likely, your `setup.sh` is not set to executable or is missing the first `#!` line that marks its interpreter.

**EDIT:**

Make sure to set `shell=True` to execute it via the shell, if you pass it as a single string, or separate the parameters into a list, as you might with `execve`:

```
subprocess.call(['sh', './setup.sh'])
```

Comment: I have tried, but it says OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Set `shell=True`, in that case.  This will ask Python to execute the command via your shell (it's basically the same as `os.system()`, then.)  Or explicitly separate 'sh' and the parameters in a list.

Comment: Yes, now it is working fine. However, I noticed that python just kept running. Does that mean I cannot not move on while this is executing?

Comment: If you want a separate process, use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`.

Answer (score 1):

Give `subprocess.Popen()` a try, with cwd param:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sh', './setup.sh'], cwd='/dir/contains/setup.sh/')
```